# Fail to deploy Next js app using App router to firebase hosting

Tags: next.js, google-cloud-functions, firebase-hosting

I have a nextjs app using the app router. It has several dynamic routes like:

> /app/doc/[id]/page.tsx]

When I try to deploy it to firebase hosting (using "firebase deploy --only hosting:project-name") it says:

```
Building a Cloud Function to run this application. This is needed due to:
 • Image Optimization
 • non-static component /doc/[id]/page
```

and then

```
Error: Failed to list functions for project-987abc
```

I have this project on blaze plan, so cloud functions is available.

After searching for a solution I found [this link](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/discussions/4980). which says to add the next js dynamic routes to firebase rewrites. After doing that I don't get the above mentioned error. But now it gives a new error:

```
⚠  functions: Your current project quotas don't allow for the current max instances setting of 100. Either reduce this function's maximum instances, or request a quota increase on the underlying Cloud Run service at https://cloud.google.com/run/quotas.
⚠  functions: You can adjust the max instances value in your function's runtime options:
    setGlobalOptions({maxInstances: 10})
Failed to create function projects/project-987abc/locations/us-east1/functions/ssrproject
```

I have tried to reduce the maxInstances in the firebase.json file. But it doesn't seem to work.

```json
"functions": [
    {
      "source": "functions",
      "codebase": "default",
      "ignore": [
        "node_modules",
        ".git",
        "firebase-debug.log",
        "firebase-debug.*.log"
      ],
      "predeploy": [
        "npm --prefix \"$RESOURCE_DIR\" run build"
      ], 
      "maxInstances": 3
    }
  ]
```